# Can we omit the main parentheses for JavaScript IIFEs?

Tags: javascript, function, anonymous-function

Is there anything wrong (or bad practice) to omit the main parentheses `(...)` for JavaScript IIFEs, and use only `();` at the end and when functions expression assign to a variable?

```
let foo = function() {
  return 'Hello'
}();

// so we use 'foo', not 'foo()'
console.log(foo); // 'Hello'
```

While **TypeScript** accepts this with no warning, should we always do this?

```
let foo = (function() {
  return 'Hello'
})();
```

Comment: doug crockford like sheathing the "dog balls": `}());` which makes it look more like a unit of code. That also prevents minification and script concatenation from producing syntax errors.

Comment: If your colleagues know where you live, use the parentheses and make their life easier when they, and future you, have to read your code.

Comment: Consider the fact the `(function() { return 'Hello' }());` is a complete statement while `function() { return 'Hello' }();` is... a syntax error.

Comment: @DavidThomas yes you right,  I totally missed that point. More code readability is what we must consider when multiple ways to right code is available in the language.

Comment: @dandavis thanks..this is a nice tip for me, I was thinking about it few days ago. Now you made it easier for me to decide that `}());` is the good one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should **ALWAYS** wrap immediately invoked functions in parentheses. It makes it much more clear that it is an IIFE and omitting parens CAN cause syntax errors. It wont always, but is the two characters really worth the ambiguity?

If you don't wrap your function, then I, as another developer examining your code in the future, would have to know to scroll to the bottom of your function before I would know that it's being invoked and not a function definition.

Comment: I like the "have to scroll down" part.

Comment: Yes, the 'scrolling' idea can be easily be missed, this is very convincing...thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer "yes" but because you normally would not assign to var. You would enclose in parens to contain the definition and force "scope", it would exist only for that moment, and the () after it would actually execute it.

Answer (score 0):

IIFE functions may don't return any value from itself so in these case you don't need to assign IIFE result to a variable. If you don't wrap IIFE by parentheses and don't assign it to variable you get syntax error. so using parentheses in IIFE is necessary.